# csv import. the file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost, csv-import

i have a problem with my code, i try to upload csv file, it was working a couple days ago, but when i try again this morning. it doesnt work. the error said that "the file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed.".

well, i use codeigniter, and csvimport for library. I do not know whether this effect. for additional information , a few days ago i update wamp server before i try to upload a second time.

my controller code :

```html
public function tambahsoal(){

  $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
  $config['max_size'] = 1000;

  $this->load->library('upload',$config);
  $this->upload->initialize($config);

  if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
   $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
   $this->load->view('dosen/hasilup',$data);
  }else{
   $file_data=$this->upload->data();
   $file_path='./upload/'.$file_data['file_name'];
               //bla bla i code again for get everthing in my csv file.
  }
  
  
 }
```

the result will be in if condition. "the file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Thanks you.

Comment: Please remove the `$this->upload->initialize($config);` because you already declare the $config on the `$this->load->library('upload',$config);`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have `$this->upload->initialize($config);` in your code.

Please remove it. Because the $config is already passed on to your `$this->load->library('upload',$config);` so there is no need to initialize it again.

```
public function tambahsoal(){

        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
        $config['max_size'] = 1000;

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        //$this->upload->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('dosen/hasilup',$data);
        }else{
            $file_data=$this->upload->data();
            $file_path='./upload/'.$file_data['file_name'];
               //bla bla i code again for get everthing in my csv file.
        }


    }
```